# Setting input field using bookmarklet

Tags: html, bookmarklet

Hi I'm trying to set the value of an input field using a bookmarklet so when I open the bookmark it will automatically set the field name? Any idea how to do this? Would like to set the field txtEmail. Thanks!

This is the HTML of the website:

```
<input id="txtEmail" class="popUpEmail" type="text" onblur="populateTheEmailField(this);" onclick="blankTheEmailField(this);" value="asdfsa@gmail.com"/>
```

I'm happy to contact me

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript: var f = document.getElementById("textEmail"); f.value = "Tagada"; void(0);
```

Comment: In one line : javascript:document.getElementById("email).value = "pepe@g.com";void(0);